# working with the command prompt in Java

Tags: java

I've been learning java on my own and I've come to a point where I need to pass arguments from the command prompt. I had previously been using Netbeans, which has become a bit of a crutch, but I want to learn how to program using notepad and the command prompt. I am running Windows 8.1. I downloaded the JDK 7 to my C:\ directory. I tried typing "java -version" and "javac -version" to check it out (as my book says to do) but it tells me "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." It says the same when I try javac. I do this from C:\ and from C:\Java> and get the same result. I uninstalled Netbeans, thinking maybe it was interfering somehow ... still not working. The book I'm using says it covers Java 7.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Is there some compatibility issue with Java 7 and win 8.1? My java 7 is update 71 or 72. Did this update change something and now arguments are passed differently? Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Try installing the software after you download it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the JDK (if you don't already have it) and add the location to the end of your PATH. In a single command line session you can do this with `PATH=%PATH%;<jdk location>` where `<jdk location>` is the bin folder of the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Some installs of java manage environment variables and some do not. It appears yours has not. or you have not installed it correctly.

many applications understand JAVA_HOME, so you should set that to the root of the installation in your environment variables.

You will also need to add the bin folder to your path.

Generally, when using windows, you can install a windows exe version, which will manage all of this for you. Other installations just copy themselves to the c drive and expect java applications to know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System environment variable. Select Variable PATH. Click on edit button. Append a ; after current value of Variable value. Copy jdk's bin folder path. In my PC it is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin" without quotes. Then paste jdk's bin path. Copy jre's bin folder path. In my PC it is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\bin". Append a ; then paste jre's bin folder path. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the JDK from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). Run the installer.
2. Open the Command Prompt. Try it. It works. Yay!

Answer (score -1):

If you use the full path to your java.exe, you dont need to set up any PATH and JAVA_HOME:

```
c:\> cd \work
c:\work> c:\java\bin\java.exe -cp classes\ your.Main
```

If your book does not use the normal JDK installers it really is supposed to explain that. (However it is normal behaviour for any executable).

(The above example asumes you compile into `c:\work\classes\your\Main.class` and your JDK is installed (installer does the unpack) in `C:\java` (typically you would use default locations like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe`).

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was able to get it to work by changing the PATH variable from the command prompt. I appreciate all of your help.